# Search for text in windows using java

Tags: java, windows

I have this directory like D://../../
and inside this folder there are many folders and in those folders there are many properties files *.properties. I want to search for a particular text in all properties files in that D directory.How to do that in java?

I have tried this

```
File f = new File( "D:/Code" );


File[] matchingFiles = f.listFiles( new FilenameFilter()
{
    public boolean accept( File dir,
                           String name )
    {
        return name.endsWith( ".properties" );
    }
} );
```

but it is searching only in D:/Code/ not in  sub folders.

Comment: First you should start writing code. And when you come in Trouble, you can come back

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and consider [edit]ing your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! this question is very broad. I would recommend googling for some tutorials and then if you run into more specific problems or exceptions, you can ask them here.

Comment: Flagged as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FileUtils.listFiles` from Apache to iterate through the files (not the listFiles method of File, as you did in your extended question):

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

You define an IOFileFilter that only accepts `*.properties` files. Having a list of those files, you read them with e.g. `FileUtils.readLines` and look for the String.

Comment: Have a look at the link I provided.